Azure AD AP can we create custom user identity to access Allow back end API access associated with Azure AD Application?
I Have Azure Ad application MyApplication which contain 10 to 12 microservices.
In expose api i have already

I have created my user custom identity to access azure ad app

I need to use my user manage identity to generate token for my all
microservice beside my azure add app below is my scope
api://axxxxxxxxxx/AllowAnonymus
 string clientId = "XXXX"; // The Client ID of the user assigned identity

        AccessToken token = await new DefaultAzureCredential(
            new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
            })
            .GetTokenAsync(
                new TokenRequestContext(
                    new[] { "api://axxxxxxxxxx/AllowAnonymus" }
                ));

I m not able generate token with this code. any one have idea

Note that: It is not possible to assign delegated permissions to Azure managed identity. Refer this SO Thread by juunas.

Using Managed identities you would not be able to sign in as a user. and hence you cannot assign delegated permissions to  managed identity.
Only Application type API permissions can be assigned to managed identity.

If you are adding scope under Expose an API tab, then it is a delegated scope:

And hence you cannot assign this kind of permission to user managed assigned and generate token.
As a workaround, you can instead create app roles in the Microsoft Entra application:

Now assign this app role to User managed identity:
Connect-AzureAD

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId MIObjectID -Id AppRoleID -PrincipalId MIObjectID -ResourceId MicrosoftEntraServicrPrincipalObjID



ObjectID and PrincipalId will be:
Go to Enterprise application -> Search your managed identity (with filter as All applications):

ResourceID is the Microsoft Entra Service principal objectID:

Now, you can generate token by using below code:
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "XXX"; // The Client ID of the user assigned identity

        AccessToken token = await new DefaultAzureCredential(
            new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
            })
            .GetTokenAsync(
                new TokenRequestContext(
                    new[] { "api://XXX/.default" }
                ));

        Console.WriteLine(token.Token);
    }
}

Note that: Managed Identity cannot be used locally because the security boundary of the managed identity is the Azure resource to which it is attached to.

Hence you need to make use of VMs, Web Apps or any other Azure resources to enable the identity and run the code. Refer this Microsoft QnA
Refer this blog by Vikas Hooda, for step-by-step implementation.


yup i did same steps it should be working

from where we can get -Id AppRoleID @Rukmini

Go to App roles in the application and check the ID that is the approleID

-ResourceId from where i can find

It is the MicrosoftEntraServicrPrincipalObjID go to entreprise app of the application and copy the Object ID

1 .-ObjectId MIObjectID= Object (principal) ID of manage identity
2-Id AppRoleID =App roles in the application and check the ID that is the approleID
3-PrincipalId MIObjectID = Object (principal) ID of manage identity
4-ResourceId MicrosoftEntraServicrPrincipalObjID= Object ID
of Enterprice application

Yes its correct

which value you added here ? api://XXX/.default  is it Application (client) ID ?

Yes its clientid

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
